# how to get the html document size with js?

Tags: javascript, file, dom, size

How can you get the actual file size(not in pixels,in bytes) of the document a js script is running on? The solution should work in all major browsers.

Comment: @Petre - Which file are you referring to. The Html file that was loaded into the browser?

Comment: @Julian Yes the html file that was loaded in the browser

Comment: I can't think of a viable option outside of an Ajax request as mentioned below. Perhaps parsing all DOM elements and checking length of both inner and outer HTML. But that would be quite error prone, slow and ludicrous. :)

Comment: @pellepim I also had that in mind and dropped it as the DOM will not reflect the exact size of the file that created it.

Comment: @Julian I'm curious of the OP purpose.  I think if you explain why you are trying to achieve this, you'll get better advise.

Comment: @Eric - what is OP ? By the way it's not my question - just tried to help Petre.

Comment: @Julian Original Poster. And oops that was supposed to be @Petre and I typed your name, sorry if I confused you.

Comment: @Petre: you can try `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML.length` should give the "raw" length of the whole HTML document - not sure if that's what you're after though.

Answer (score 4):

//

```
function hrefSize(){
    try{
        var O= new XMLHttpRequest;
        O.open("HEAD", document.URL, false);
        O.send(null);
        if(O.status== 200){
            return O.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    catch(er){
        return 0;
    }
}
alert(hrefSize()+' bytes');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could propably refetch the page via ajax and get the length of it as a string, but this will be suboptimal because it will trigger another HTTP request and have to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as close as you'll get to viewing the full source for a page using ***only*** JS:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

You could use the returned string as a starting point for the file size. If you need to consider images, their sizes would have to be added on manually by traversing the DOM tree and inspecting each `img` element. This could be done easily via a jQuery or similar library selector:

`$("img").each(function() {...});`

If you need to further consider elements like Flash and Java, there is no way to do this completely with JS. You'd have to run an AJAX request and let the server tell you the sizes of referenced files.